# AWS create role - Has prohibited field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying out a simple example suggested by AWS documentation to create a role using a policy json file
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html
And I get the error

```
A client error (MalformedPolicyDocument) occurred when calling the CreateRole operation: Has prohibited field Resource
```

Here's the command,

```
>> aws iam create-role --role-name test-service-role --assume-role-policy-document file:///home/ec2-user/policy.json
A client error (MalformedPolicyDocument) occurred when calling the CreateRole operation: Has prohibited field Resource
```

The policy is the exact same as the one mentioned in the example

```
>> cat policy.json 
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example_bucket"
  }
}
```

My version seems to be up to date

```
>> aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.9 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.3.9
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The policy document should be something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

This is called a trust relationship policy document. This is different from a policy document. Whatever you have pasted is for the policy attached to a role which is done using [attach role policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/attach-role-policy.html)

Even the above role document is given in the link you have pasted.
This should work. I have worked on roles and policies and I can say with certainty.

Even in the AWS console, for roles you can see that there is a separate tab for trust relationship. Also you have currently attached policies in the permissions tab.

Comment: Getting same error while use following --
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "Service":"s3.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
      }
   ]
}

and it above policy is given in AWS doc. then why I am getting error ?

Comment: @NeerajRathod specify the error. Never say "some error".

Comment: That policy creates an IAM role without Instance Profile ARNs, how is it possible to have it?

Comment: This policy "Has prohibited field Principal"

Answer (score 1):

The AWS message, 
*An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json* 
appears if you don't use the full pathname. For instance, using

```
--assume-role-policy-document myfile.json
```

or even a nonexistent.file.json, causes the problem.

The solution is to use

```
--assume-role-policy-document file://myfile.json
```

An here is the content for my Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {"Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"},
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the original error message, which is about *a prohibited field*.