# Terraform: Error creating IAM Role. MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

My TF code is giving me an error:

```
  /*
   * Policy: AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess
   */
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

I copied and pasted the Policy from https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess$jsonEditor

```
* aws_iam_role.<role name>: Error creating IAM Role <role name>: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
status code: 400, request id: <request id>
```

Not sure why it's saying Resource is prohibited.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188013/aws-create-role-has-prohibited-field

Comment: You're setting your policy stuff in the `assume_role_policy`, which is where you should be defining the policy of who can assume this role, not what this role can do. Try moving this policy to a `aws_iam_policy` resource and setting this `assume_role_policy` how @Gangaraju shows below.

Answer (score 50):

- Need to define `assume_role_policy` with `sts:AssumeRole` (Who can assume this role, ex: EC2 service).
- Policy can be directly attached using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` instead of duplicating existing policy.

  ```
  resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_iam_role" {
    name = "ec2_iam_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": [
            "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
  }

  resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2-read-only-policy-attachment" {
      role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_iam_role.name}"
      policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess"
  }
  ```

Comment: What if you wanted to add additional permissions at the Resource level as well as the Service level? I.e. an ARN of another IAM role in addition to the Service. Or would you need to create separate roles at that point?

Comment: You can add one more statement with IAM role instead of service to the same assume role policy or you can create another role also. You try generating and simulating your policies at https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html,  https://policysim.aws.amazon.com

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue when using role arn. When I tried using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` - I was getting error for role name having unsupported characters.

What worked for me for to create a `aws_iam_role_policy` as below:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "api-invoker" {
    provider = <some provider>
    role     = aws_iam_role.api-invoker.id
    policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.execute-api.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "execute-api" {
    statement {
     sid = "all"
     actions = [
       "execute-api:*",
     ]
     resources = [
       "*"
     ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while i am creating a policy to assume role from another AWS account. So, I have added another AWS account Id in the trusted entities then the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #create i am user for account-1
resource "aws_iam_user" "user-1" {
  name = "my-user"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "my-user"
  }
}

# create policy for 2nd account
resource "aws_iam_policy" "prod_s3" {
  provider    = aws.aws02
  name        = "prod_s3"
  description = "allow assuming prod_s3 role"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect   = "Allow",
        Action   = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Resource = "arn:aws:iam::940883708906:user/my-user"
    }]
  })
}
# Attach the policy
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "prod_s3" {
  provider   = aws.aws02
  user       = aws_iam_user.user-1.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.prod_s3.arn
}
# create assume role
resource "aws_iam_role" "prod_list_s3" {
  provider = aws.aws02
  name     = "role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect    = "Allow",
        Action    = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Principal = { "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.utils.account_id}:root" }
    }]
  })
}
# output arn
output "role-arn" {
  value = aws_iam_role.prod_list_s3.arn

}
# create caller identity
data "aws_caller_identity" "utils" {
  provider = aws.aws02
}
# create s3 full access for 2nd account and attach the file
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_all" {
  provider    = aws.aws02
  name        = "s3_all"
  description = "allows listing all s3 buckets"
  policy      = file("role_permissions_policy.json")
}
# inside the file 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
**strong text**
# Attach the assume role
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "s3-all-att" {
  name       = "list s3 buckets policy to role"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.prod_list_s3.name}"]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_all.arn
  provider   = aws.aws02
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).