# Error creating IAM Role. MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource. Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have seen several links, but I have to see an example.
I have:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "role"

  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1590217939125",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe"
      },
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1590217939125",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe/*"
      },
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1577967806846",
        "Action": [
          "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
          "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
          "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
  EOF
  tags = {
    Name        = wwe
    Environment = STAGE
  }
}
```

When I am making,

```
terraform apply
```

I see this:

```
  # aws_iam_role.role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = "s3:*"
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::wwe"
                      + Sid      = "Stmt1590217939125"
                    },
                  + {
                      + Action   = "s3:*"
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::wwe/*"
                      + Sid      = "Stmt1590217939125"
                    },
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                          + "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
                          + "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
                          + "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                          + "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
                          + "secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
                        ]
                      + Effect   = "Allow"
                      + Resource = "*"
                      + Sid      = "Stmt1577967806846"
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + force_detach_policies = false
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + max_session_duration  = 3600
      + name                  = "role"
      + path                  = "/"
      + tags                  = {
          + "Environment" = "STAGE"
          + "Name"        = "wwe"
        }
      + unique_id             = (known after apply)
    }
```

After, when I am writing `yes`, I see:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
        status code: 400
```

Where, I have an error ? Please don't post links, to the same questions. I don't understand, where I have an error, Could You please write an example, where I have an error, If it possible.
Thanks for Your attention.

Comment: Something similar, which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565879/terraform-error-creating-iam-role-malformedpolicydocument-has-prohibited-fiel/44581645

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One issue is that you have two statements with the **same Sid**: `Stmt1590217939125`.

Sids must be **unique**. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_sid.html):

> In IAM, the Sid value **must be unique** within a JSON policy.

The second issue is that `assume_role_policy` is for a **trust policy**. Trust policies **do not have Resource**. They have different form. For [instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html):

```
 assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

To add your policies to the role, you have to use [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html). For example, you could do:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "my-role"
   description = "My policy"

  policy = <<-EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1590217939128",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe"
      },
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1590217939125",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe/*"
      },
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1577967806846",
        "Action": [
          "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
          "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
          "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## What's wrong with the existing code?

The **assume_role_policy** attribute of the [**aws_iam_role** resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings),  is not for granting permissions to calls APIs other than **sts:AssumeRole**:

> assume_role_policy - (Required) The policy that grants an entity permission to assume the role.
>
> NOTE: This assume_role_policy is very similar but slightly different than just a standard IAM policy and cannot use an aws_iam_policy resource. It can however, use an aws_iam_policy_document data source, see example below for how this could work.

## How do I fix it?

So, assuming you want this role to be assumable by EC2, you would use an **aws_iam_role** to declare the IAM Role and its **assume_role_policy**:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "role"

  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF
  EOF
  tags = {
    Name        = wwe
    Environment = STAGE
  }
}
```

And then use an **aws_iam_role_policy** to attach an inline policy with the IAM actions you wish to grant that role (along with resources and possible conditions):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "policy" {
  name = "policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.role.id

  policy = <<-EOF
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe"
        },
        {
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wwe/*"
        },
        {
          "Action": [
            "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
            "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
            "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

You don't need to tuck your JSON along the margin, it can be indented for improved readability:

> Terraform also accepts an [indented heredoc string](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-literals) variant that is introduced by the <<- sequence:
>
> ```
> block {
>   value = <<-EOT
>   hello
>     world
>   EOT
> }
> ```

I recommend using an [**aws_iam_policy_document**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) data source to build your IAM policies. It's avoids annoying quirks of JSON (like no trailing commas) and better supports scenarios where you need to use variables in building your policies (really difficult to escape them properly in all cases):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "policy" {
  name = "policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_doc.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::wwe",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::wwe/*",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
      "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
      "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
      "secretsmanager:ListSecrets",
    ]

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }
}
```