# Terraform Codedeploy Role Policy - MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm Creating an AWS Code Deploy IAM Policy for S3 using Terraform, But Getting Error MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource.

**main.tf file:**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_iam_role" {
  name = "AutoScalePolicy"
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/AutoScalePolicy.json")
  tags = {
    Name = "AutoScale-CodeDeploy-BlueGreen-Role"
  }     
}
```

Here is the AutoScalePolicy.json:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:PutAccessPointPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-demo",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-demo/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

Tried changing the IAM Policy and S3 Bucket names but still the isssues persist. had troubleshooted with these issues:

1. [AWS create role - Has prohibited field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34188013)
2. [Terraform: Error creating IAM Role. MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44565879)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Please post your terraform code as text. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IAM, there are two kinds of policies: [trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#term_trust-policy) and [permissions policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#term_policy).

- A permissions policy specifies what the role can do.
- A trust policy
  specifies who can assume the role.

In `assume_role_policy`, you specify a trust policy. It does not define what the role can do, but rather who can assume it.

It should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"},
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

which just tells that CodeDeploy can assume this role.

You `AutoScaleDeploy.json` is a permissions policy. You can either specify it inline:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "codedeploy_trust" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codedeploy.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "codedeploy_iam_role" {
  name = "AutoScalePolicy"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.codedeploy_trust.json
  inline_policy {
    name   = "autoscale"
    policy = file("${path.module}/AutoScalePolicy.json")
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "AutoScale-CodeDeploy-BlueGreen-Role"
  }     
}
```

or, if you intend on reusing it for other roles, create a managed policy and attach it to your role:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "auto_scale" {
  name        = "test-policy"
  description = "A test policy"
  policy      = file("${path.module}/AutoScalePolicy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "auto_scale" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.auto_scale.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AutoScalePolicy.json` is a policy, and not an an assume_role_policy. You should use something like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  ...
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })

  inline_policy {
    name   = "role_policy"
    policy = file("${path.module}/AutoScalePolicy.json")
  }
  ...
}
```

The resource [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#argument-reference) mentions the difference between a policy and an assume role policy.